# При передаче префаба в скрипт, он равен null

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: префаб в скрипте]

Вроде префаб вставил в переменную, однако при попытке создать этот префаб через Instantiate() юнити говорит, что переменная shell равна null. Проверял через Print(), но он тоже пишет null. Переменная shell не меняется в коде
Скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject shell;
    Camera cam;
    GameObject rotateAxis;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        rotateAxis = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RotateAxis");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 camMove = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0);
        Vector3 aim = new Vector3(0f, 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Aim"));
        if (cam.orthographicSize - Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel") <= 4 & cam.orthographicSize - Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0.1f)
            cam.orthographicSize -= Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        cam.transform.Translate(camMove * 0.002f);
        rotateAxis.transform.Rotate(aim * 0.05f);
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Fire1") == 1)
            Instantiate(shell, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ShellSpawn").transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ShellSpawn").transform.rotation); //тут исключение
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код скрипта, и укажите, в какой строке возниаает исключение.

Comment: Исключение на 27-ой строке, оно и понятно

Comment: Напишите комментарием в коде, точно где.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что проблема в shell, а не в FindGameObjectWithTag()?

Comment: Shell написал с большой буквы, то же самое. Я пробовал закомментировать всё тело метода update и оставить только Print(shell). То же самое. Всё дело в shell

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html почитайте документацию, вдруг что-то упустили.

Comment: Всё верно вроде. Разве что там используется присваивание Instantiate(), но я не уверен, что это как-то влияет. Здесь дело в том, что shell равен null

Comment: Control - какое-то общее имя, в дотнете часто встречаются стандартные классы с таким именем. Из разряда бреда, попробуйте переименовать скрипт более специфичным именем.

Comment: А ещё можно проверить один ли у вас `Control`, вдруг вы поле одному заполнили, а запускается другой?

Comment: Всем спасибо. Я решил банальным это созданием нового скрипта с переносом всего кода туда. Надо было попробовать это с самого начала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил банальным это созданием нового скрипта с переносом всего кода туда.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).